# Hive - where older than x days

Tags: date, amazon-web-services, hive, amazon-athena

In AWS Athena table I have a timestamp column which looks like,

```
select  eventtime from cloudtrail_logs limit 1
```

---

```
eventtime
--------- 
2016-10-21T01:18:28Z
```

I need to get the eventtime which are older than 7 days.

I tried `current()`, `unix_timestamp` but no luck.

Comment: Just to verify? What is the type of the column?

Comment: its String type

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select  *
from    cloudtrail_logs 
where   eventtime >= date_format(current_date - interval '7' day,'%Y-%m-%d')
;
```

For clarification:

```
select date_format(current_date - interval '7' day,'%Y-%m-%d');
```

> 2017-03-12

Comment: See updated answer. Using only the date should be enough.